# Visual Studio 2013 native cordova app build error

Tags: google-chrome, visual-studio-2013, ripple, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I just installed and repaired my VS2013 to build Native Cordova App. I have also installed the latest version of NodeJS but whenever I am trying to build the Application It gives me an error. I am uploading an image for more details on error as I believe image provide more info than text.[image]

Posting error details if error is not clear in an image

1. Cannot find module 'q'.
2. The command ""C:\Users\nnnc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\vs-cli" prepare --platform Android --configuration Debug --projectDir . --projectName "BlankCordovaApp1" --language "en-US"" exited with code 8. C:\Users\nnnc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets

I have advanced a little bit more but having hard time to run the application I have to manually installed all the required module. but now whenever I am running my project I get an error of web page is not available. please look at the attached image again.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the fix and that Involved manually loading packages like q via node js and in the end the fix for web page is not available was that ripple has changed and now we should not add it as an extension via chrome. it should be done via node js as well as below

```
npm install ripple -g
```

but before doing that delete it from chrome if you have got it otherwise just run the command.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

I found that running `npm install` from within /vs-mda/ solved all my problems.